# Convert pdfContentByte to byte array or System.IO.Stream in c#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, pdf

I am adding an digital signature image into a existing PDF from share point document library. I am able to get the file and add the image into it. but after that I am facing issue to upload the edited file to share point library.

I have used the iTextSharp DLL for this.which creates the object of pdfContentByte. but to save this file to sharepoint I need to convert it into the Stream. Any kind of help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(signFileInfo.Stream); 
image.SetAbsolutePosition(450, 50); pdfContentByte.AddImage(image); 
stamper.Close(); 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, location, fileInfo1.Stream, true);
```